# ICMP Ping in WinRT - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-runtime, icmp

How to do an ICMP ping in a WinRT Modern UI application?

Ping is not implemented in WinRT currently (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952346/is-it-possible-to-write-a-ping-class-in-c-sharp-that-will-run-within-windows-8-m)) and the previous strategies in Silverlight being:

- Use a WCF Service
- Call Javascript which then calls an ActiveX component
- Give up ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893743/tcp-ping-in-silverlight))

Vasily [here](https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-vasily#readme) uses http to 'ping' a webserver on a specific port using StreamSocket which supports network communication using a TCP socket.

Perhaps [Windows.Networking.Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR226960)s is the highest level API I have to use if I want to write my own ICMP library for WinRT..

[This](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/icmp-using-raw-socket-not-working-vista-t3235397.html) implementation uses System.Net.Sockets to make an ICMP echo request - in standard .NET

[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DatagramSocket-sample-76a7d82b#content) WinRT sample uses the Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket class to create a UDP socket.  I think what I need is raw sockets to do ICMP.

Is this even possible in the WinRT sandbox to ICMP ping?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
try
            {
                using (var tcpClient = new StreamSocket())
                {
                    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(
                        new Windows.Networking.HostName(HostName),
                        PortNumber,
                        SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

                    var localIp = tcpClient.Information.LocalAddress.DisplayName;
                    var remoteIp = tcpClient.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName;

                    ConnectionAttemptInformation = String.Format("Success, remote server contacted at IP address {0}",
                                                                 remoteIp);
                    tcpClient.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.HResult == -2147013895)
                {
                    ConnectionAttemptInformation = "Error: No such host is known";
                }
                else if (ex.HResult == -2147014836)
                {
                    ConnectionAttemptInformation = "Error: Timeout when connecting (check hostname and port)";
                }
                else
                {
                    ConnectionAttemptInformation = "Error: Exception returned from network stack: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                ConnectionInProgress = false;
            }
```

full source here:  [github](https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-vasily)

Comment: Thanks - I believe StreamSocket is TCP transport level, so can't be made to work to create ICMP pings.

Comment: do you need to actually use Ping or simply duplicate the functionality?

Comment: Yes I need to use an ICMP ping :-)  Unfortunately a port 80 or 443 request isn't good enough.